# Link mongoDB instance database to meteor local

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, meteor, database

I've recently setup an ec-2 instance to deploy a meteor application on AWS. My app works correctly with mongoDB database.

Now I want to connect my meteor project's database to the EC2 database and then I've tried some command lines :

- start my meteor project with a new mongo url with the following command line : ***"MONGO_URL="mongodb://username:password@xx.xx.xxx.xxx:27017/Tasks" meteor"*** but it returns the following [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyLgV.png)
- connect to mongo with the other following command line :
  ***"meteor mongo --url xx.xx.xxx.xxx:27017"*** but it returns a timeout. I thought it was due to the lack of username and password however when I add this option meteor does not assume the command.
- connect to mongo in my js collection file with 
  ***"export const Tasks = mongoose.connect("mongodb://username:password@xx.xx.xxx.xxx:27017/Tasks").connection;"*** but it returns "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED" (second [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUip9.png))

Is there any tips to manage to establish database connection from local meteor ?

Thank you for answer,

Martin

Comment: I'm curious about the `mongoose.connect` line, are you using mongoose?

Comment: I have import mongoose through le line "var mongoose = require('mongoose');".

Is this you're asking for ?

Comment: you're using mongoose with meteor? Seems a bit unusual

Comment: I've tried different ways, this one is for me the worst but I notify it. Do you know an other way ?

Answer (score 0):

If the database and the Meteor processes are in the same machine, you can call it from "localhost".

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://user:password@localhost/Tasks"
```

If you really want to use the IP + Port approach, you have to ensure that it's accessible from the [EC2 Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) you're using.

The same applies for connecting manually in Mongoose **but you should't be using Mongoose with Meteor**, it has it's [own way of handling collections](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html). If you need something more powerful, or a way to extend it yourself checkout the [Meteor Simple Schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) project.